# Is it possible to prove algebraically that $\left[ \frac{(1-s)^{1/x}+(1+s)^{1/x}}{2} \right]^x$ decreases with $x$, for $x$ and $s$ in $(0,1)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

> Is it possible to prove algebraically that this expression decreases with $x$?
> $$\left[ \frac{(1-s)^{1/x}+(1+s)^{1/x}}{2} \right]^x$$
> where $s \in (0,1)$ and also $x \in (0,1)$.

I solved it numerically and I know it's true, but I can't solve it algebraically.

The denominator $2^x$ increases with $x$ while the numerator $ \left[ (1-s)^{1/x}+(1+s)^{1/x} \right]^x$ decreases. Taking the derivative does not seem to help, as the expression becomes relatively complicated.

Comment: Do you mean *decreases* ?

Comment: I would start by considering the expression in the square brackets. It's always $>1$ in the defined area.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I mean decreases.

Comment: @MattiP. thanks but I don't see how this helps

Comment: @MattiP. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Maybe try to take the logarithm and differentiate. And do you mean for $x>0$? because it is not true for any open interval of x containing $0$.

Comment: Note the following:

$$\left[ \frac{(1-s)^{1/x}+(1+s)^{1/x}}{2} \right]^x = \left [\frac{(1-s)^{1/x}}{2} \left(1+\frac{(1+s)^{1/x}}{(1-s)^{1/x}} \right)\right]^x$$

$$ = \frac{1-s}{2^x} \left [ \left(1+\frac{(1+s)^{1/x}}{(1-s)^{1/x}} \right)\right ]^x$$

Let $\tilde{s} := \frac{1+s}{1-s} \in (1,\infty)$

We thus have:

$$ = \frac{1-s}{2^x} [ 1+\tilde{s}^{1/x}]^x := f(x)$$ Can you move on from here?

Comment: @Dqrksun. Notice that $x \in (0,1)$. And thanks for the suggestion, I had tried that already but did not lead me anywhere.

Comment: @Tecon My bad, I didn't see that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an instance of the Power Mean Inequality.  Here is a self-contained
proof, which can be considerably generalised.  It involves calculus
(as any proof is likely to do, notwithstanding the 'algebra-precalculus' tag).

Suppose that $0 < x < y < 1.$  The function
$$
f \colon (0, \infty) \to (0, \infty), \ t \mapsto t^{y/x}
$$
is strictly convex, and the function $(0, \infty) \to (0, \infty),$
$u \mapsto u^x$ is strictly increasing, so
\begin{multline*}
\left[\frac{(1-s)^{1/y} + (1+s)^{1/y}}2\right]^y =
\left\{f\left[\frac{(1-s)^{1/y} + (1+s)^{1/y}}2\right]\right\}^x\\ <
\left\{\frac{f\left[(1-s)^{1/y}\right] +
f\left[(1+s)^{1/y}\right]}2\right\}^{x} =
\left[\frac{(1-s)^{1/x} + (1+s)^{1/x}}2\right]^{x}.
\end{multline*}